# Is there a way to authorize vanity domains for Google APIs?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, subdomain, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am implementing vanity domains for an app that uses several Google APIs. I would like to keep the interaction with these Google APIs client-side as much as possible. But, I notice the documentation states Javascript origins `can't contain wildcards or paths`. Is there a work around?

How can I enable `*.example.com` for Google Javascript origins? Am I going to have to write my own service?

Comment: Please let me know which GCP service are you using.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I am using Docs and Drive. I am not hosting on GCP.

Comment: Thank you. Please do not use tag `google-cloud-platform` next time if you don't use GCP services.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Will do!